# Text in child div goes out of parents max width

Tags: css, html

So i have this problem with divs. I have one div containting two other divs that are next to eachother, problem is that in the right div I have bunch of text and i want that text to start a new row when it goes to div #1 (his parents) max width.

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="parent"> 
   <div id ="left"></div>
   <div id ="right">
        blahblablabla
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the property `word-wrap:break-word;` in your CSS for `<div id ="right">`. You may also need to set `overflow-x: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to put `<div id="left">` inside `<div id="right">` and just make the right div width = 100%?